# Blank space being produced from for loop for dates

Tags: c#, dynamic, panel

I have a loop that iterates through each date between two selected dates.

It creates a panel for each product on that date and then moves on.

That works fine, but if I run the loop again, it produces a blank space between the new panels and the old panels. Here is a example:

(small cause of my small screen)

[image: Black Lines]

The black lines indicate what I'm speaking about. The short one is the normal spacing between each panel and the long one indicates when I run the loop again.

The reason I'm worried is because if you want to add products after your initial add, it will be the second or third or fourth time the loop runs and leave that gap which just creates an unpleasant view.

Can someone please tell me what is causing this gap, here is the code for this section(i know about the SQL injections, i do send parameters to a DAL but for the sake of this question I'm using a SQL query):

```
for (DateTime date = dtpSDate.Value; date.Date <= dtpCDate.Value; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
     pnlReport.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = date.ToString(), Height = 20, Width = 150, Name = date.ToString(), Location = new Point(20, globalY), Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold) });
     globalY += 30;
     foreach (DataRowView lstvItem in chkListProducts.CheckedItems)
     {
           DataTable ProdTmp2 = new DataTable();
           string sqlP2 = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProdID = '" + lstvItem[this.chkListProducts.ValueMember] + "'";
           ProdTmp2 = db.GetDataTable(sqlP2);

           if (Side == "Left")
           {
                Panel pnltmp = new Panel();
                pnltmp.Size = new Size(472, 120);
                pnltmp.Location = new Point(5, globalY);
                pnltmp.BackColor = Color.Green;
                pnltmp.Name = ProdTmp2.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                Label l = new Label();
                l.Text = ProdTmp2.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                l.Location = new Point(5, 5);
                pnltmp.Controls.Add(l);
                pnlReport.Controls.Add(pnltmp);
                Side = "Right";
                last = ProdTmp2.Rows[0][1].ToString();
           }
           else
           {
                Panel pnltmp = new Panel();
                pnltmp.Size = new Size(472, 120);
                pnltmp.Location = new Point(487, globalY);
                pnltmp.BackColor = Color.Red;
                pnltmp.Name = ProdTmp2.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                Label l = new Label();
                l.Text = ProdTmp2.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                l.Location = new Point(5, 5);
                pnltmp.Controls.Add(l);
                pnlReport.Controls.Add(pnltmp);
                Side = "Left";
                globalY += 140;
                last = ProdTmp2.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            }
     }

     if (Side == "Right")
     {
          Side = "Left";
                globalY += 170;
     }                
}
```

Extra Info: The bigger the date gap. The larger the blank space gap.

Comment: Could db.GetDataTable(sqlP2) return noting on subsequent calls?

Comment: @SpaceghostAli I don't see why. Cause if it gets something the first time and parameters don't change. It has to be getting something the subsequently.

Comment: this seems the offensive piece of code, it will add 170 to globalY everytime you finish your foreach over chkListProducts.CheckedItems

[code]
     if (Side == "Right")
     {
          Side = "Left";
                globalY += 170;
     }    
[/code]

Comment: @BruceBurge do you think adding it in an if loop to check if its the last checkbox in the date before it executes the piece of code you commented it on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the end Code looks like this and the space is now non existent. 
Thanx to all.

```
private void AddProducts()
    {
        foreach (Panel p in pnlReport.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
        {
            if (p.Name == last)
            {
                globalY = p.Location.Y + 140;
            }
        }

        for (DateTime date = dtpSDate.Value; date.Date <= dtpCDate.Value; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            pnlReport.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = date.ToString(), Height = 20, Width = 150, Name = date.ToString(), Location = new Point(20, globalY), Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold) });
            globalY += 30;
            foreach (DataRowView lstvItem in chkListProducts.CheckedItems)
            {
                string table = "";
                string select = "";
                if (Regex.IsMatch(lstvItem[this.chkListProducts.DisplayMember].ToString(), @"^[a-hA-H]"))
                {
                    table = "ProductHistoryAH";
                }
                else if (Regex.IsMatch(lstvItem[this.chkListProducts.DisplayMember].ToString(), @"^[i-qI-Q]"))
                {
                    table = "ProductHistoryIQ";
                }
                else if (Regex.IsMatch(lstvItem[this.chkListProducts.DisplayMember].ToString(), @"^[r-zR-Z]"))
                {
                    table = "ProductHistoryRZ";
                }

                DataTable ProdTmp1 = new DataTable();
                string sqlP1 = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE ProdID = '" + lstvItem[this.chkListProducts.ValueMember] + "' AND ProdHDate = '" + date.ToString(@"yyyy\/MM\/dd") + "'";
                ProdTmp1 = db.GetDataTable(sqlP1);

                DataTable ProdTmp2 = new DataTable();
                string sqlP2 = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProdID = '" + lstvItem[this.chkListProducts.ValueMember] + "'";
                ProdTmp2 = db.GetDataTable(sqlP2);

                if (Side == "Left")
                {
                    Panel pnltmp = new Panel();
                    pnltmp.Size = new Size(472, 120);
                    pnltmp.Location = new Point(5, globalY);
                    pnltmp.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    pnltmp.Name = ProdTmp2.Rows[0][1].ToString() + count.ToString();
                    //Name
                    Label lblName = new Label();
                    lblName.Text = lstvItem[this.chkListProducts.DisplayMember].ToString();
                    lblName.Location = new Point(5, 5);
                    pnltmp.Controls.Add(lblName);
                    int Location = 0;
                    //Count
                    if (chkPCount.Checked)
                    {
                        Label lblCount = new Label();
                        if(ProdTmp1.Rows.Count>0)
                        {
                            lblCount.Text = "Count: " + ProdTmp1.Rows[0][4].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblCount.Text = "Count: 0";
                        }                            
                        lblCount.Location = new Point(17, 32);
                        pnltmp.Controls.Add(lblCount);
                    }                                              
                    pnlReport.Controls.Add(pnltmp);
                    Side = "Right";
                }
                else if(Side == "Right")
                {
                    Panel pnltmp = new Panel();
                    pnltmp.Size = new Size(472, 120);
                    pnltmp.Location = new Point(487, globalY);
                    pnltmp.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    pnltmp.Name = ProdTmp2.Rows[0][1].ToString() + count.ToString();
                    //Name
                    Label lblName = new Label();
                    lblName.Text = lstvItem[this.chkListProducts.DisplayMember].ToString();
                    lblName.Location = new Point(5, 5);
                    pnltmp.Controls.Add(lblName);
                    //Count
                    if (chkPCount.Checked)
                    {
                        Label lblCount = new Label();
                        if (ProdTmp1.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            lblCount.Text = "Count: " + ProdTmp1.Rows[0][4].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblCount.Text = "Count: 0";
                        }
                        lblCount.Location = new Point(17, 32);
                        pnltmp.Controls.Add(lblCount);
                    }                        
                    pnlReport.Controls.Add(pnltmp);
                    Side = "Left";
                    globalY += 140;                                         
                }
                last = ProdTmp2.Rows[0][1].ToString() + count.ToString();
            }
            if (Side == "Right")
            {
                Side = "Left";
                globalY += 140;
            }          
        }
        count++;
    }
```

and the output:

[image: Output]